# Howto split stdin into multiple multiline strings and put each of them into different bash variables

Tags: bash, pipe, string, stdin, split

I'm searching for a possibility to send via pipe several multiline strings to a bash script and grab each of them within this script. Finally, I want to store each multiline string into its own variable.

```
printf "$some_multiline_string" "$another_multiline_string" | some_script.sh some_params
```

Inside of bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
file1=$(</dev/stdin)
file2=$(</dev/stdin)
...
```

How to split stdin into multiple multiline variables?

Comment: How would you know when file1's input was done?

Comment: Why don't you use the multiline strings as parameters, and keep them with ${@} to get the number of parameters, and then run with a simple loop and assign them to var?

Comment: I tried to pass them as parameteres. and it worked, but seems there is a limit, which I'm easily reaching with large files.

Comment: If you have very long streams, then use files. Keep them into single file where each line describes a string, then make the script to run on it.
Or you can make each string a file, and run over a list of files.

Comment: So i should put each multiline string into it's own (temporary) file and read their content from within the bash script? if yes, i hope this intermediate will not take too much time else....? Had the hope there is a more easy but still super fast way to pass huge data (from php) to a shell script?

Comment: It really depends what you need the script to do. If it is something simple, the quickest way would be writing this data to a file (single file) and separate string with an empty line. Then run your script on this file. You can use 'time' binary to check how long it takes to execute.

Comment: If you're passing "huge data" then you almost certainly do not want to be using a shell script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use the environment?

```
export some_multiline_string another_multiline_string
```

And then you can access those variables from within the script.

If they may be very large and exceed the maximum size of an argument/envvar or if combined they exceed the maximum size of the arg+env list, then you could pass them with pipes:

```
myscript 3< <(printf %s "$some_multiline_string") \
         4< <(printf %s "$another_multiline_string") args
```

And within `myscript`:

```
IFS= read -rd '' -u3 var1
IFS= read -rd '' -u4 var2
exec 3<&- 4<&-
```

Or you could pass them from within a single stream for instance on the script's stdin but delimited with NUL (which in `bash` can't occur in a variable):

```
printf '%s\0' "$some_multiline_string" "$another_multiline_string" |
  myscript args
```

And within `myscript`:

```
IFS= read -rd '' var1 && IFS= read -rd '' var2
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but I think what you are looking for is:

```
script.sh "$some_multiline_string" "$another_multiline_string" param1 param2
```

Then, inside the script, you would have:

```
file1="$1"
file2="$2"
param1="$3"
param2="$4"
```

If you really need to pipe it, you could do something like this:

```
printf '%s\0%s' "$str1" "$str2" | script.sh param1 param2
```

And, in the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
param1="$1"
param2="$2"

strings=()
while IFS= read -d '' str; do
    strings+=("$str")
done
printf 'String 1: %s\n\nString 2: %s\n' "${strings[0]}" "${strings[1]}"
```

For example:

```
$ str1="this is
a multiline
string"

$ str2="this is
another multiline
string"

$ printf '%s\0%s\0' "$str1" "$str2" | foo.sh
String 1: this is
a multiline
string

String 2: this is
another multiline
string
```

In bash versions 4.4+, you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash
param1="$1"
param2="$2"

strings=()
readarray -t -d '' strings

printf 'String 1: %s\n\nString 2: %s\n' "${strings[0]}" "${strings[1]}"
```

Comment: Thank you all, this and the top one solution helped me a lot.